# x64 calculating forward jumps

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, machine-code

If you have an instruction that jumps forward, is there a way to calculate an offset address or do you just calculate an absolute jump on the second pass-through?

Like this:

```
Jump to Label
Move 0 to 64bit Register 1
Label:
Move 0 to 64bit Register 2
```

Do compilers just use absolute jumps in cases like these?  I mean it is possible to calculate the offset in a simple case like this but it becomes exponentially more expensive with more labels, not to mention jumps and labels nested in each other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a nice problem, not that hard to solve though. The solution is not to use absolute jumps - that doesn't even solve anything. You'd have to know the address of the target, and if you know that you probably also know the current address and you could do a relative jump. So that's a dead end.

A simple solution is to do two passes (or "one and a half") over the code, in the first pass you collect all the addresses (you can't emit the code because at this point you don't know anything about forward references yet), on the second pass you use this information to emit all the code with branches and everything. "One and a half" pass emits the code and placeholders for branches, then comes back to fill in the offsets of the branches. This avoids having to parse again.

That has a problem though, the first pass can't decide whether it can use a short jump or a normal one, so it actually can't know the code size. But it could take a guess, and then you can iteratively fix every branch that references a label outside of its range by replacing that branch by a wider one. You can also go the other way around, starting with full jumps and then try to replace them by shorter ones.

Comment: Is it worth it to condense the normal jumps to short ones?  Seems like it would take a whole lot of passes to change them all in a normal program...

Comment: @RyanBrown yes, if you use big jumps everywhere it costs a lot of code space (and thus cache space, and more cache misses, etc). It doesn't really take a lot of time to do it, much less than parsing the input and so on - it usually finds the fixed point (where no more jumps can be shortened, or from the other way, no more jumps have to be widened) in a couple of iterations